# setting nginx container as a proxy for another app

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy

I am trying to setup an nginx container that will show at the "http://server_ip/" path the nginx html page and on the "/app" path the tutum/hello-world container. as a follow up, want to be able to get to the "hello-world" container only from the "http://server_ip/app" path and not via http://server_ip:1500.

I created the following docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services: 
  proxy:
    container_name: proxy
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - $PWD/config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
    networks: 
      - backend
  webapp:
    container_name: webapp
    image: tutum/hello-world
    ports: 
      - "1500:80"
    networks: 
      - backend
networks: 
  backend:
```

then I have the following nginx.conf  file:

```
server {
    listen 80; # not really needed, but more informative
    location = / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    location = /app/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1500/;
    }
}
```

If I try to get to each of the containers by their http://server_ip:PORT, I get there. if I try http://server_ip/app  I get "404 not found". what am I missing? did I put the conf file in the wrong folder? how do I limit the availability of the "hello-world" only to the "http://server_ip/app" path and not via "http://server_ip:1500".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your containers using the "backend" docker network, as you stated in the compose file.
Inside that they reach each other with the service names, so from the "proxy" service you can reach "webapp" service on http://webapp (or http://webapp:80) and from the "webapp" service you can reach "proxy" on http://proxy or (http://proxy:80).

On your computer if you type http://localhost:1500/ you will reach the webapp service and if you type http://localhost:80/ you will reach proxy service.
The port mapping 1500:80 means that your computer 1500 port is mapped to the webapp container 80 port.

So in nginx.conf do this:

```
proxy_pass http://webapp:80/;
```

Also if you want to make your webapp not accessible from your host on localhost:1500 remove the ports part in the webapp service spec:

```
version: '3'
services: 
  proxy:
    container_name: proxy
    image: nginx:1.11
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - $PWD/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks: 
      - backend
  webapp:
    container_name: webapp
    image: tutum/hello-world
    networks: 
      - backend
networks: 
  backend:
```

Comment: this doesn't do anything. I am aware that since they are in the same compose file they can "see" each other through DNS but I am trying to make the "http://myip/app" the proper url to get there and not "http://webapp"

Comment: You want to reach the webapp from your computer browser on http://localhost/app right?

Comment: yes. but I am not sure my `conf` file is written correctly and whether I mounted it in the right place

Comment: I see, ok, so my answer about the nginx configuration line is right, you must do that. OTOH your volume mapping is wrong as you can not mount files like you try to do (I am not sure that it is even possible). You can mount the directory the same way as you mounted html, see my update in answer.

Comment: not entirely sure why mounting the folder instead of the file itself fixed it, but it works. On a side note, you **can** mount specific files in accordance to [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag)

Comment: You are right, it should work with files too. Are you using Docker Desktop for Windows (WSL2) ? I am, maybe this is a docker-compose bug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229020/discussion-between-zsolt-and-killerz0ne).